# Resources for Modeling Box Office Decline Curves with Weekend Spikes

Tags: online-resources

I am interested in fitting decline curves of daily movie box office results. I've found plenty of resources targeting oil well decline curve analysis that largely work well, except the decline curves of movies have spikes relating to weekends.

Any resources, recommendations, etc. on decline curves with spikes every several periods?

[image]